# Get a property from all child objects of child objects of...a variable depth object

Tags: javascript

I  have an object like this

```
test: {
    title: '1'
    parent: {
        title: '0'
        parent: {
            title: '-1'
            parent: {
                title: '-2'
}   }   }   }
```

and then there aren't any `parent`s further down (for this `test` object, but it could be for others).

I need to make string `1 0 -1 -2`... for all `test` objects regardless of their depth.

```
var title = test.title + test.parent.title + test.parent.parent.title + ...
```

But since I don't know in advance how deep the chain goes for all of them and could be different for different objects, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29), you can traverse the object, returning at each step the concatenation of the title and the children titles.

```
var collectTitles = function (node) {
    var result = node.title;
    if (node.parent) {
        result += collectTitles(node.parent);
    }

    return result + ' ';
};

var title = collectTitles(test);
```

What would happen is that at the first step, `collectTitles` will be called on `test`; `node.title` being '1', it will be set as the value of `result` variable. Since `test` contains `parent`, the condition will match, and `collectTitles(test.parent)` will be evaluated in turn, and its result concatenated to '1'.

The same operation will be repeated for `test.parent`, `test.parent.parent` and `test.parent.parent.parent`. For this last one, `result` would be set to '-2', and since it doesn't have a `parent`, the function will return the actual '-2' string. The final result would be:

```
1·0·-1·-2·
```

If having a leading space is not acceptable, you can do one of the following:

- [Trim the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim),
- [Remove the last character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) from the string, or:
- Return an array instead of a concatenation, and [join this array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).